# Probability measures only equivalent on a subset of the sample space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**Question:** Suppose $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and consider
$$2^X = \{\emptyset, X, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{1,2,4\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{2,3,4\}\}.$$

Let $B \subset 2^X$ such that $\sigma(B) = 2^X$. Is it possible to construct two probability measures $m_1, m_2$ over $X$ such that $m_1 \neq m_2$  on $2^X$, but $m_1 = m_2$ on some $B$?

**My idea:** I figure the smallest $B$ under such constraints would be a good start. So, $B = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\}, \{3\}\}$, and $\sigma(B) = 2^X$, Then $m_1(A) = m_2(A), \forall A \in B$.  Also, our measures must satisfy:

- $m_i(\emptyset) = 0$, $m_i(X) = 1$
- For any disjoint combination $A_1, A_2, \dots \in 2^X$ we have

$$m_i\left(\bigcup A_j\right) = \sum m_i(A_j), ~~~ \bigcup A_j \in 2^X,$$

$~~~~~~~$for each $i \in \{1,2\}$.

I tried to play around with the left out singleton $\{4\}$. So, something like, $m_1(A) = \frac{\#(A\setminus \{4\})}{\#(X \setminus \{4\})}$, and letting $m_2(\{n\}) = \frac{1}{3}$ for $n \in \{1,2,3\}$. But I haven't found an $m_2$ in this way that satisfies the disjointness property above. Perhaps I should choose a different $B$?

Comment: Well, by definition probabilities already have $m_1(X)=m_2(X)=1$.

Comment: Sure, I included for completeness. If they weren't probability measures you could just say $m_2(\{\text{any set with $4$}\}) = \infty$, and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $B = \{\{2,3\},\{3,4\}\}$. It is easy to check that $\sigma(B)$ contains all singletons and so $\sigma(B) = 2^X$. For convenience, I will now denote a probability measure $m$ on $2^X$ as a $4$-tuple $m = (m^{(1)},m^{(2)},m^{(3)},m^{(4)})$, where $m^{(i)} := m(\{i\})$. Now consider the probability measures $$m_1 := (\frac 16, \frac 13, \frac 16, \frac 13),\quad m_2 := (\frac 13, \frac 16,\frac 13, \frac 16).$$ Clearly, $m_1\neq m_2$, but $$m_1(\{2,3\}) = m_2(\{2,3\}) = \frac 16 + \frac 13 = \frac 12,$$ and $$m_1(\{3,4\}) = m_2(\{3,4\}) = \frac 16 + \frac 13 = \frac 12,$$ so $m_1$ and $m_2$ agree on $B$.

Comment: It is unclear to me what $m_1(\{2\} \cup \{3\})$ is given the definition of your measures? It would be $m_1(\{2,3\}) = m_1^{(\{2,3\})} =$ ? It's clear that $m_1(\{2\}) + m_1(\{3\}) = 1/2$. I think you need to further define $\nu_1(A) = \sum_{i \in A} m_1(\{i\})$ if $A \neq \emptyset$, otherwise 0. An equivalent definition for $\nu_2$ follows.

Comment: @user334916 A measure $\mu$ on a countable sample space $(\Omega,2^\Omega)$ is uniquely determined by the weight it assigns to singletons by the relation $$\mu(A) = \sum_{i\in A} \mu(\{i\}),\quad A\in 2^\Omega.$$ It is thus sufficient to specify these weights, which I denoted by $\mu_i,\, i\in \Omega$ in this case.